# Allow Only Numbers and a Dot in the following Format with Regex javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have an input field which should get filled by the user with only numbers and a singel dot/comma and only in the following format. 
This should occure `.on("input")` meaning as the user types it should secure the right input format.

A wrong char should be replaced with a blank.

Format Example: 
 1.000 
1.281
 21212.000
 21212.810
Nothing like this:
1.02.12 
or 
1919,201,00
 Only a dot between the two Number blocks.

This is what i have so far:
    Regex 1:

```
$("body").on("input", "#testId", function(){
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

Regex 2:

```
$("body").on("input", "#testId", function(){
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9]+\.+[0-9]{1,3}/g,'');
});
```

Regex 3:

```
$("body").on("input", "#testId", function(){
     this.value = this.value.replace(/[0-9]+\.+[0-9]{1,3}/g,'');
});
```

I think i am doing something wrong with the `replace()` method.
Unfortunately none of them work as i want to. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ucmd6eh5/2/)

Should Work in IE11

Comment: how it should replace if a user entered `11.10,33` ?

Comment: like this 11.1033

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this. make sure your input type is **tel** which will allow you to have numeric keypad in mobile browser

```js
const regex = /[^\d.]|\.(?=.*\.)/g;
const subst=``;



$('#testId').keyup(function(){
const str=this.value;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
this.value=result;

});
```

```css
.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<input id="testId" type="tel" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer thank you. Unfortunately i need to have input type number since i use it on a mobile device(Number Keyboard). Is there  a way to realize it with type="number" ?

Comment: couldnt do it with parseInt() or toString()

Comment: @TheWandererr you can try with type="tel" which will allow you numeric keypad for your mobile device

Comment: there is a way to restrict to allow only 2 number after the dot? https://jsfiddle.net/xwbv4a1u/8/

Answer (score 2):

try this one,

```
^[0-9]*(\.|,)?[0-9]*$
```

this take below cases:

1111,
.0000
123,12
12.12
12345

but if you want only

111,11
11.11
12345

so please use this

```
^[0-9]+(\.|,)?[0-9]+$
```

to force use dot/comma please use this

```
^[0-9]+(\.|,)[0-9]+$
```

add this code

```
$("#testId").keyup(function(){

   var vals = $("#testId").val(); 

   if(/^[0-9]*(\.|,)?[0-9]*$/g.test(vals))
    $("#testId").val(vals);
     else
    vals = vals.replace(/.$/,"");

    $("#testId").val(vals);
  });
```

and change input type to

> type="text"

Comment: can you try again

Comment: your regex are correct as I see, but something wrong in the fiddle, I think it should be fixed before mask using

Comment: Your updated answer will allow this  -->just a  .    or just a   ,      which is incorrect